# Split file based on a key and name the output with the key name

Tags: linux, awk

does any one know how to split a file based on a key and name the relatedoutput with the respective key name. Thanx in advance

Input

```
>mail9.country1(+):38689378-38709400
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>father
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>mother
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>son
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>daughter
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------

>mailX.countryX(+):000000-3111111110
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>father
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>mother
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>son
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>daughter
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
```

Output files should be like below with their respective content

mail9.country1(+):38689378-38709400.mail

```
>mail9.country1(+):38689378-38709400
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>father
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>mother
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>son
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>daughter
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
```

mailX.countryX(+):000000-3111111110.mail

```
>mailX.countryX(+):000000-3111111110
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>father
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>mother
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>son
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
>daughter
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------HHHHHHHH------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'>' '$2~/^mail/{f=$2".mail";gsub(/[)(]/,"_",f)}{print > f}' file
```

Comment: I need the files with their respective input. sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: What is the respective input? Given your example this produces the excepted output. Please edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: one more thing. Is there anyway to replace "(" or ")" tokens with "_" in the file names. thanx

Comment: "sudo_O: One more small request. Hope I am not annoying you. How can I change the key name inside the files to mail. Every file should have "mail" instead of the full keyname (>mail9.country1(+):38689378-38709400 or >mailX.countryX(+):000000-3111111110). However, file name should be the full key name like before.

Comment: Use the `gsub` function again to do the replacement before the `print` statement.

Comment: Like this ? awk -F'>' '$2~/^mail/{f=$2".mail";gsub(/[)(]/,"_",f);gsub(/[mail*]/,"mail",f)}{print > f}'

Comment: Put it inside the block, something like: `awk -F'>' '$2~/^mail/{f=$2".mail";gsub(/[)(]/,"_",f)}{gsub(/mail[^ ]*/,"mail",f);print > f}' `

Comment: It is changing the file name but the key inside the file. I need exactly the opposite.